# Can $\{(x,y) \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ can be written as the cartesian product of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

We consider the set
$$S := \{(x,y) \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1\}.$$
The exercise in Munkres asks whether it is possible to write this set as the cartesian product of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. We, naturally, consider restricting ourselves to the interval $(-1,1)$. If $|x|, |y| \geq 1$, then $x^2 + y^2 \geq 1$, so we require $|x|, |y| < 1$. Hence, the set $(-1,1)$ should work. However, if I take, say, $x, y = \frac{3}{4}$, I get
$$\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 = 2 \cdot \frac{9}{16} = \frac{9}{8} > 1,$$
so this construction fails.

I cannot figure out how to prove rigorously (and generally) that no such construction would work because it's possible that there is some kind of restrictions, maybe to $\left(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$, for example, that I am missing. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if you use intervals, what shape will the product have? What shape are you trying to get?

Comment: I believe the shape would be a square, right?

Comment: If $(a,b) \in A\times B$ and $(c,d) \in A\times B$ then it must be that $(a,d)$ and $(b,c)$ must also be in $A\times B$.  So as $(0, 0.99)$ and $(0.99,0) \in S$ so if $S$ *were* a cartesian product the $(0.99,0.99)$ would have to be in $S$ which it isn't.

Comment: How do we know that $(a,d)$ and $(b,c)$ must also live in $A \times B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $S = A \times B$ with $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Since $(t,0)^T,(0,t)^T \in S$ for any $t\in (-1,1)$ we must have $t \in A$ and $t \in B$ and so we must have $(t,t)^T \in S$, and we have $t^2+t^2 = 2t^2$.

We can choose any $t$ satisfying $|t| \ge {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: The given set is the open, not closed ball. The argument is essentially the same, but needs a little modification.

Comment: What do $e_1$ and $e_2$ correspond to here?

Comment: @JohnP.: I replaced by unambiguous notation.

Comment: I appreciate that. (I assume you must have meant standard basis vectors?) Can I ask how we conclude that $(t,t)$ is in $S$ if $(t,0)$ and $(0,t)$ are in $S$? If $(t,0) \in S$, then $t^2 < 1$. But how do we know that $t^2 + t^2 < 1$?

Comment: Oh, I understand. This is the definition of a Cartesian product. Ok, thank you!

Comment: If $(a,b) \in A \times B$ then we must have $a \in A, b \in B$. So, if $(t,0)^T \in A \times B$ we must have $t \in A$, and similarly for $B$. Since I started assuming that $S = A \times B$, if $(t,t) \in S$ we must have $t^2+t^2 < 1$, so by picking $t$ close to $1$ we get a contradiction.

Comment: @DonThousand: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Since $(0,0.99)$ and $(0.99,0)$ are in the set, $0.99\in A,B$, where $A,B$ are two sets whose cartesian product contains the given set.

But, $(0.99,0.99)$ is not in the given set, so $A\times B$ is in fact, not equal to the set. So, it is not possible.